# Snakemake - How do I use each line of a file as an input?

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake

I need to use each line of the file `tissuesused.txt` as an input for a parallelized rule in snakemake. I think there are about 48 jobs I would like to call in total.

```
for line in $(cat tissuesused.txt)
do
   echo "Sorting $line.phen_fastqtl.bed to $line/$line.pheno.bed..."
   bedtools sort -header -i $line/$line.phen_fastqtl.bed > $line/$line.pheno.bed 
   echo "bgzipping $line/$line.pheno.bed..."
   bgzip -f $line/$line.pheno.bed
   #figure out where tabix outputs
   echo "Indexing $line/$line.pheno.bed.gz..."
   tabix -p bed $line/$line.pheno.bed.gz
done
```

How would I go about doing this in snakemake? I can't find anything on this online. This job occurs halfway through the pipeline and therefore I don't know how I would go about defining a function at the top of the snakefile for a file that isn't there yet. I would just like to create a list of strings which each contain an abbreviation for a type of human tissue found in `tissuesused.txt`. I found a [section in the snakemake docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#functions-as-input-files) that look like they might be relevant but I am not sure how I would apply it to my case. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Here's what I have so far, not sure if it'll work:

```
def fileAsList(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            lis = []
            spl = line.split()
            lis.append(spl[0])
        return lis
...
rule sort_zip_ind_pheno:
    input:
        tis=fileAsList("tissuesused.txt"),
        chk=".make_tis_dirs.chkpnt"
    output:
        touch(".sort_zip_ind_pheno.chkpnt")
    shell:
        "bedtools sort -header -i {input.tis}/{input.tis}.phen_fastqtl.bed > \
        {input.tis}/{input.tis}.pheno.bed;"
        "bgzip -f {input.tis}/{input.tis}.pheno.bed;"
        "tabix -p bed {input.tis}/{input.tis}.pheno.bed.gz"
```

Please let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are [checkpoints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution) in Snakemake. Take a look at this example:

```
checkpoint get_tissue:
    output:
        "tissuesused.txt"
    run:
        with open(output[0], 'a') as f:
            for i in range(9):
                f.write(f"{i}\n")


rule read_tissue:
    output:
        "tissue_{n}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo "this is tissue {wildcards.n}" > {output}
        """


def read_tissues_output(wildcards):
    with open(checkpoints.get_tissue.get().output[0]) as f:
        samples = [sample for sample in f.read().split('\n') if len(sample) > 0]  # we dont want empty lines
        return expand("tissue_{sample}.txt", sample=samples)

rule all:
    input:
        read_tissues_output
```

and run it with

`snakemake --until all`

Rule all uses `read_tissues_output` as input function (just as you specify in the question). This function then tries to open the output of checkpoint `get_tissue`, and if it doesn't exist yet it will generate it. Once the output exists the function reads the file, and returns the files we want to generate (`tissue_{1-10}`). Rule `read_tissue` can generate then generate these files (in parallel) for us.

**edit**:

tissueused.txt:

```
WHLBLD
TESTIS
THYROID
```

Snakefile

```
def read_tissues_output():
    with open('tissuesused.txt') as f:
        samples = [sample for sample in f.read().split('\n') if len(sample) > 0]  # we dont want empty lines
        return expand("tissue_{sample}.txt", sample=samples)

rule all:
    input:
        read_tissues_output()


rule read_tissue:
    output:
        "tissue_{n}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo "this is tissue {wildcards.n}" > {output}
        """
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer; I should have specified that the file `tissuesused.txt` already exists in this case and has strings per line such as: `WHLBLD\nTESTIS\nTHYROID` etc. I want to use these strings as variables which then complete the paths and filenames of the files I wish to manipulate.

Comment: @CelineDion, I thought the tissuedused.txt was generated dynamically by some rule. In that case use checkpoints. If it already exists, then you can just read the file like I did in the edit.

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande Hi I tried to use your approach for a dynamic situation, where I generate a file, who's lines are used as wildcards for future filenames. Would you care to elaborate on where the lines from the input file are readed, and how they are provided as input for the other rules?