# How to use every line in .txt file as new input for snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have a file 'filenames.txt' with in it:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

I want to use these lines as input in snakemake. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snakemake - How do I use each line of a file as an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57597910/11613622) (refer second part of the answer)

Comment: I do not know anything about snakemake so cannot really answer your question. But have you tried googling something like `dynamic import` or `dynamic file names` or similar?  A quick search yields several results for me including: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57327210/snakemake-dynamically-derive-the-targets-from-input-files (this is a slightly different approach that will read all .txt files in a directory, but something to think about). With your approach I assume you can just read original filenames.txt, then loop through each line, and inside the loop read each file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python inside a snakefile. Here is how you could obtain a list of file names:

```
with open('filenames.txt') as fh:
    filenames = [line.strip() for line in fh]
```

Then, I'm not sure how you intend to use those file names.
If you want your workflow to create those files, it should be made the `input` section of the top `all` rule:

```
rule all:
    input: filenames
```

And you should of course have a rule that can create such a file:

```
rule create_file:
    output: "{letter}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        touch {output[0]}
        """
```